# establishing proper relationship between entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

User profile has profile attributes on the system. 
That attributes can be of different types (AboutYou, Occupation, AnyhingElse).

Now I want to establish proper relationship between :

1. profile and profile attributes
2. profile attributes and profile attributes type (I dont want to use enum as datatype)

Profile.cs

```
public List<ProfileAttribute> Attributes {get; set;}
```

ProfileAttribute.cs

```
// holds user entered response on particular subject
// describe yourself (if aboutYou type is selected)
public string Response {get; set;}
public ProfileAttributeType {get; set;}
```

ProfileAttributeType.cs

```
public List<ProfileAttribute> Attributes {get; set;}
public string AttributeType {get; set;}
```

This is legacy code and db, and I'm trying to build app using ddd approach and generated db tables, so I'm stuck on the following.

One `Profile` has many `ProfileAttribute`. So I have `one to many` via profile side.

I cannot figure relationship via `ProfileAttribute` side.  Does all profileattributes belongs to one profile or is it `many to many`? This Response property confuses me. How would you do it?

Also, for ProfileAttribute and ProfileAttributeType I have following

One `ProfileAttribute` has many `AttributeType`(s) via `ProfileAttribute` side, and via `ProfileAttribute` side I have `many to one` (Many types can belong to Many ProfileAttributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it seems strange that `ProfileAttributeType` would itself contain a collection of `ProfileAttribute`. Perhaps it would have a collection of attributes of a dedicated type?

As far as the relationship between `Profile` and `ProfileAttribute`, the attribute should be a **value object** associated with the profile **aggregate**. This means that the relationship is one-to-many. In other words, one Profile can contain many attributes, however an attribute belongs to a single profile. Attributes themselves can be grouped by attribute type. The attribute type can itself be an **entity** or **aggregate** if there are behaviors associated with attribute types.